# SOAP call between 2 applications, both deployed on Websphere application server - SSL/HTTPS enabled

Tags: java, web-services, soap, websphere, soap-client

I am facing an issue - I have two java application e1 and e2 deployed on WebSphere application servers was1_6.x and was2_7.x respectively, both WAS are SSL/HTTPS enabled.
e1 is making a SOAP call to e2 but error occurs on both sides as below:

```
error on e1 logs - javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem    parsing  [https://vm32iw3r2:9449/EngageOneWS/RequestStatusUpdateService?wsdl].: java.net.SocketExceptionat com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(Unknown Source)

error on e2 logs - Unable to initialize SSL connection.  Unauthorized access was denied or security settings have expired.  Exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
```

Please suggest!

Thanks, Shailendra Singh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

e1 doesn't recognize e2's SSL certificate. You need to add it to the keystore. See http://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-java-keytool-keystore-commands.html